# sharepoint physical asset tracker

Tags: android, sharepoint

I'm new to sharepoint and would like to create a physical asset tracker.

I still don't fully understand how sharepoint works but can this be done with sharepoint? I'd like it to be accessible with both a computer and an android phone. Do I need to create an app for both sharepoint and android?

I am thinking of using barcode, qr code or RFID tags to keep track of new Electronic equipments purchased and keep track of where each item is at a given time within the building (multiple floors).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For viewing on Android, YMMV depending on what version of SharePoint you're running. There are Android apps out there to make SharePoint on Android a nicer experience but even those are... mixed... in my experience.

Regarding tracking, I'd say it can be done but not OOTB or very easily. I imagine you'd need a separate program that's handling all the incoming barcode/QR/RFID information and then updating a SharePoint list accordingly via REST or something...